# Unity 5.3: What's the equivalent of UnitEngine.Application.loadedLevel?

Tags: c#, deprecated, scene, unity-game-engine

Pre Unity 5.3, I had the following code:

```
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
```

This would advance the current level by one, which is handy for moving to the next level in a multiple level game. However, I noticed that both `LoadLevel` and `loadedLevel` are deprecated. I've found a pretty good equivalent code for the `LoadLevel`, but I'm struggling to find anything that advances the level by one, or a current scene indicator. Any suggestions?

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SceneManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) has a function called [GetActiveScene](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html)(), which returns a [Scene](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html). The scene has a getter called buildIndex that returns the build index. That value is the same as the previous loadedLevel. Thus, the code should be the following:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

Comment: if you wanted to reload the current scene, you could use: SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

Comment: I am trying to reload onto the current scene but it still says there is a compile error.  My scene name is GucioDevs.  -- SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GucioDevs);